# Ruby to Objective C Bridge

Tags: ios, objective-c, ruby

I have a barcode scanner device and its SDK for native iOS. I have delegates for all the events for the device and its working fine. But I have to create an application in Ruby to access the external accessary. If any one know how to write Ruby to objective-c bridge, please share few tips.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: http://www.rubymotion.com/

Comment: i don't understand why you need to do it in ruby? how is this going to work anyways? rubymotion is not going to help, as it gets compiled to bytecode. the only iOS Ruby bridge right now is mobiruby: http://mobiruby.org/

Comment: Its based on customer requirement. Have to build a hybrid app for both Android and iPhone. Customer specifically asked for Ruby. I think Ruby motion will not help me much. Thanks guys for your reply :)

Comment: Your customer doesn't have a technical clue then (which is no surprise-- many of my customers didn't either in the 10+ years I did consulting services).   Building an iOS app in Ruby with the hope of somehow making it cross platform with Android makes no sense at all.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the RubyMotion project?

It's designed to work with Ruby and iOS.

http://www.rubymotion.com/